# foreach data on bootstrap slider showing data in rows

Tags: php, foreach, slider

This is code for image slider with little bit text on image. This code showing images in a rows.
But I want to make it slider. So, please help me.

```
                  <?php $isFirst = true; ?>
                  <?php foreach ($summaries as $key => $Summary){  ?>
                      <div class="item{{{ $isFirst ? ' active' : '' }}}">
                        <?php
                            if($Image){ 
                          ?>
                            <?= $this->Html->image('../img/'.$Image[0]['Image']['name'],array('class' =>"img-responsive imgslider"));  ?>
                        <?php } else{ ?>
                            <?= $this->Html->image('new_dummy.png',array('class'=>'img-responsive imgslider')); ?>
                        <?php }; ?>
                        <div class="carousel-caption" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)">
                          <h3><?= $Summary['Summary']['dhalao_id']?  $Summary['Dhalao']['name'] : 'Root'; ?></h3>
                          <p>Quantity Report: <?= $Summary['Summary']['time_created'] ;?> && Time: <?= $Summary['Summary']['date_created']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <?php $isFirst = false; ?>
                  <?php }; ?>
```

Here, I created `$isFirst` variable, what stays true until first slide has been printed. This way we can add active class for first slide and not for others.

Comment: by "make it a slider", do you mean "make it one row with a slider"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use default format of php. start with  tag in line

```
 <div class="item{{{ $isFirst ? ' active' : '' }}}">
```

and apply condition like following:

```
<div class="item <?php echo ($isFirst) ? ' active' : '' ; ?>">
```

Comment: This is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap the html of carousal is like this :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
     <?php $isFirst = true; ?>
                      <?php foreach ($summaries as $key => $Summary){  ?>
                          <div class="item{{{ $isFirst ? ' active' : '' }}}">
                            <?php
                                if($Image){ 
                              ?>
                                <?= $this->Html->image('../img/'.$Image[0]['Image']['name'],array('class' =>"img-responsive imgslider"));  ?>
                            <?php } else{ ?>
                                <?= $this->Html->image('new_dummy.png',array('class'=>'img-responsive imgslider')); ?>
                            <?php }; ?>
                            <div class="carousel-caption" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)">
                              <h3><?= $Summary['Summary']['dhalao_id']?  $Summary['Dhalao']['name'] : 'Root'; ?></h3>
                              <p>Quantity Report: <?= $Summary['Summary']['time_created'] ;?> && Time: <?= $Summary['Summary']['date_created']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      <?php $isFirst = false; ?>
                      <?php }; ?>
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I'm saying its bootstrap slider so I already use all Bootstrap tag for its slider but thanks for your time.